# Steady-State temperature in heat equation over a wedge

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, steady-state

In preparation of a upcoming exam I have came across the following problem and I am not quite sure how to complete this problem and am looking for some help finding this solution, thanks!

I need to find the steady state temperature in a wedge shaped flat plate occupying the region $0\leq r \leq1, 0\leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{4} $ (which are polar coordinates). The edges $\theta = 0 $ and $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$ are kept at zero temprature and the arc $ r = 1 (0 < \theta < \frac{\pi}{4})$ is kept at constant temperature,

Do you need to use the laplace transform to solve this?

$$\Delta u = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2 } + \frac{\partial^2 u }{\partial y^2} = 0 $$

I know that the steady state solution is $$k^2 \frac{\partial^2 u }{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial t } = 0 $$
 so then $$\frac{\partial u^2}{\partial x^2 } =0 $$ and then $$u(x,t)=Ax+b $$ but then how do i use my conditions to solve this problem?

Comment: @Dmoreno I have made a edit but I am not actually sure where to start or how to solve this at all

Answer (score 3):

You should start by posing the heat-conduction problem. Under some assumptions, the temperature distribution in the solid is dictated by the heat equation

$$ \rho c_p T_t = \nabla \cdot (k \nabla T),$$

where $k$ is the thermal conductivity, $\rho$ is the density and $c_p$ is the specific heat of the material, $t$ is time and $T$ is temperature.

Let $\alpha = k/(\rho c_p)$ be thermal diffusivity and define the nondimensional time $\tau = t/t_c$, with $t_c = r_o^2/\alpha$, and the nondimensional radius $ r=r^*/r_o$ where $r_o$ is the radius of your plate and ${}^*$ denotes a dimensional quantity. On defining

$$ u = \frac{T-T_e}{T_i - T_e},$$

where $T_e$ is the temperature at the edges and $T_i$ is an initial temperature distribution, your problem reduces to integrate

$$u_\tau = \nabla^2 u,$$

to be integrated with initial condition $u = 1$ and boundary conditions $u = 0$ at the edges and $u = u_a$, say, at the arc.

Now let's have a look at the specific system of reference you have. Since the domain is a sector of a circle, it makes sense using cylindrical polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$. Since there's no addition of heat, the problem reaches a steady state and you don't have to care about initial conditions. Thus, the heat equation reduces to integrate:

$$ 0 = \frac{1}{r} \partial_r (r \, \partial_r u) + \frac{1}{r^2} \partial_{\theta\theta}u, \quad u = 0 \text{ at } \theta = 0,\pi/4, \quad u = u_a \text{ at } r=1 $$

This second-order PDE can be solved using, for instance, separation of variables. Let $u = G(r)\phi(\theta),$ where $G$ and $\phi$ are nonzero functions of their arguments. Introduction of the ansatz yields:

$$ 0 = \underbrace{\frac{r}{G} (r G')'}_{\lambda^2} + \underbrace{\frac{\phi''}{\phi}}_{-\lambda^2}  $$

Introducing the suitably signed separation constant $\lambda^2$ the problem in $\theta$ becomes $\phi''+\lambda^2 \phi = 0$ with $\phi(0) = \phi(\pi/4) = 0$. Nontrivial solutions are

$$\phi_n = \sin(4n\theta), \quad n = 1,2,\ldots$$

for which one may define $\lambda_n = 4n > 0$. On the other hand, for $G$, the solution to

$$  (r \, G')' - \frac{\lambda^2}{r} G = 0 \implies r^2 G'' + r G' - \lambda^2 G = 0$$

can be sought of in the form $G \propto r^\sigma$ giving

$$ \sigma (\sigma -1)+\sigma - \lambda^2 = \sigma^2 - \lambda^2 = 0$$

which provides $\sigma = \pm \lambda$ and produces solutions of the form $G\propto r^\lambda$ and $G \propto r^{-\lambda}$. On eliminating solutions that blow up at $r \to 0$, we expand $u = \sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n \phi_n(\theta)G_n(r)$, where $B_n$ are real constants and $G_n(r) = r^{\lambda_n}$. The constant(s) of integration are found with the help of the boundary condition at $r = 1$ which yields:

$$u_a = \sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n G_n(1) \phi_n(\theta)$$

Note that $G_n(1) = 1$. Multiply both sides by $\phi_m$ and integrate over $0<\theta<\pi/4$ to find:

$$ B_n =  \frac{u_a \int^{\pi/4}_0 \phi_n(\theta) \, \mathrm{d}\theta}{\int^{\pi/4}_0 \phi^2_n(\theta) \, \mathrm{d}\theta} $$

The problem is solved upon evaluation of the integrals. To that end, it's convenient to note that $\sin^2(4n\theta) = (1-\cos(8n\theta))/2$. Therefore, the integral in the denominator is just $ [ \theta/2 - \sin{(8 n\theta)}/(16n)]^{\pi/4}_0 = \pi/8$ because the sines evaluate to $0$ in $0$ and in $2 n \pi$. For the one upstairs, simply use

$$ \int^{\pi/4}_0 \sin{4n\theta} \, \mathrm{d}\theta = \left.\frac{\cos{4n\theta}}{4n}\right|^0_{\pi/4} = \frac{1 - \cos{n\pi}}{4n} = \frac{1 - (-1)^n}{4n} $$

Note that this is $0$ for $n = 2,4,\ldots$. Thus, on defining $n$ to be an odd number, $n = 2k+1$, $k = 0, 1, \ldots$, we can simplify the result to

$$B_k = \frac{2}{4(2k+1)} = \frac{1}{2(2k+1)} $$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: It should be $\phi''/\phi = -\lambda$. Then you impose the homogeneous boundary conditions to discover $\lambda = (4n)^2$.

Comment: I'm kind of stuck in the last part of my edit (I get some unexpected $\cosh$ of $\log$s from Mathematica)... Unfortunately I have to leave now but I'll get back to it later.

Comment: thanks again for the new edit, still a little confused sorry. So from here do i use the boundary conditions?

Comment: okay thanks for your time, hopefully you can come back later and finish

Comment: I think I got it. Please go over my solution and let me know it there's something wrong/not clear/missing.

Comment: okay so all i need to do now is just solve bn so i just need to do the integrals in that fraction?

Comment: I think so. You may also have to exploit the properties of the integrals as a function of $n$. For instance, the integral downstairs is just $\pi/8$ and the one upstairs is zero for even values of $n$.

Comment: how did you get the denominator to be $\frac{\pi}{8}$ i am a little confused on solving for $B_n$, but once we solve for $B_n$ we are finally done

Comment: Hint: use double-angle formulae.

Comment: not quite sure how to use that here, what is $Q_n?$

Comment: sorry for all the questions, just want to get this answer correct so i can study the process

Comment: Sorry, I used $Q$ in my notes instead of $\phi$. They mean the same.

Comment: okay so for the denom i got $${\int^{\pi/4}_0 \phi^2_n(\theta) \, \mathrm{d}\theta} = \int_0^{\pi/4} sin^2(4\theta)d\theta = \frac{\pi}{8}$$ but then for the numerator i think i am getting the right solution $$   u_a \int^{\pi/4}_0 \phi_n(\theta) = u_a \int ^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_0 sin(4\theta)d\theta=u_a\frac{1}{2}$$ so then $B_n=u_a\frac{4}{\pi}$ does that look correct?

Comment: Don't forget the $n$ in the argument of the sines. $B_n$ should depend on $n$ as well. The first integral is correct because once you use the double-angle formula, you realize that the cosine part integrates to 0, for all $n$. For the second integral, you may express the solution in terms of $\cos{n \pi} = (-1)^n$.

Comment: could you make a edit about those double angle formulas? i wasnt quite sure what to do with the n's i got a little confused. that will be the last thing, thanks btw for all this time

Comment: and what is $u_a$?

Comment: Please see my edit. I just defined $u_a$ to be the value of the (nondimensional) temperature at the arc.

Comment: awesome, so the final result just becomes$$ \frac{1}{2(2k+1)}$$ thanks so much for your time, i will spend some time now and look over this solution

Comment: No problem. Note that when you change indices from $n$ to $k$, then $k$ runs from $0$ to $\infty$ (you can work with $n$ as well if you like).